# Find the maximum of the value if $x+y+z+w=1$

Tags: inequality

This is a related problem (see here [if $x+y+z=1$ then find the maximum of the form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374389/if-xyz-1-then-find-the-maximum-of-the-form))

We have the following problem:

$n=4$ Let $x,y,z,w>0$ and such $x+y+z+w=1$ find the maximum of the value
$$x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{z}+z\sqrt{w}$$ If we continue with $n=5,6,7⋯$ there is a logical suite but I don't know how to prove this and what is the following numbers . Thanks.

Comment: from where will you know that there is a global Maximum?

Comment: Did you try to apply the Lagrange method from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374426/42969 to this case?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lagrange approach the problem can be solved. The various equations are not particular complicated, but I won't repeat them here (If you really would like to know them let me know and I add them at some later time), and results in two solutions.

The first is the one related to the previous problem, i.e. $(x,y,z,w)=(0,\frac{4}{9},\frac{4}{9},\frac{1}{9})$ and results in a local maximum $\frac{4}{9}$.

The second results in a more complicated maximum located at 
$$x = \frac{4}{123} (13 - \sqrt{5}) \approx 0.350047$$
$$y = \frac{2}{123} (17 + 5 \sqrt{5}) \approx 0.458217$$
$$z = \frac{2}{123} (13 - \sqrt{5}) \approx 0.175023$$
$$w = \frac{1}{123} (11 - 4\sqrt{5}) \approx 0.0167132$$
which results in the global maximum 
$$
\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{34 + 10 \sqrt{5}}{123}} \approx 0.451278 > \frac{4}{9}
$$